# Is it OK to say "Ask the question to your partner"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Is it OK to say "Ask the question to your partner" instead of "Ask your partner the question"?
How about "Ask the question of your partner"?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot say

> Ask the question to your partner

It can be the below though

> Pose a question **to** your partner

The below can be used

> Ask the question of your partner

Another viable option is

> Ask a question of your partner

You can check [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180294/asking-a-question-to-from-or-of) out for more info

Comment: Please don't post answers unless you are sure the information is correct!

Comment: @KateBunting Ok, I'm **quite** sure my answer is correct, but there is always a chance that I'm wrong! Thanks for the information about that though!

Comment: Fair enough, though one would hope that's everyone's attitude (I'm reasonably sure I'm right, *and* open to being corrected)!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot **<strike>ask something to someone</strike>**. It's not correct English.

You can **ask something of someone** but then it would probably be a request not a question.

> *Can I ask a favour of you?* (Oxford Dictionary)

And of course you can always **ask someone something**, and the "something" can be a question or a favour etc.

> *Can I ask you a favour?* (Oxford Dictionary)
> *Can I ask a question?* (Oxford Dictionary)
> *Did you ask the price?* (Oxford Dictionary)